# log in with foreach display just once

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make a simple log in system. I need something like this:

If the username and the password is correct display welcome else display try again. 
I have stored some names and passwords in an associative array and I have 2 variables named $username and $pass and in the array I have 3 names and 3 passwords  when I search in the array and find the name and password I want to display "welcome" and leave the loop.

```
<?php 

$username = "sconnor" ; 
$password = "fatethatwemake"; 

if ($username == "sconnor" && $password = "fatethatwemake") { 
    echo "Welcome" ;
    echo "the first if";
} else { 
    echo "Try againg";
}

echo "----------------<br>" ; 

$users = array("Dragos" => "razvan", "Cristina "=> "cristina", "Ionel" => "ionel"); 
$pass = "ionel1" ; 
$username = "Ionel1";

foreach ($users as $name=>$password) {
    if ($name == $username && $password == $pass) { 
        echo "$name  welcome your password is $password"; 
        break; 
    } else {
        echo "try again<br>"; 
    }
}
```

My problem is that after the "welcome" is displayed the "try again" is also displayed twice because I have 2 more users. I tried with a break and it works if the user is correct but if the users is inccorect then "try again" is displayed 3 times and I want just one time .

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code. just you forgot a '=' `$password="fatethatwemake"` in the if condition

Comment: If you want a simple login system, use http auth and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` like [explained in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag to check for login success. Try below code.

```
    $flag = 0;
    foreach($users as $name=>$password)  
    {
            if($name==$username && $password==$pass) { 
                echo "$name  welcome your password is $password"; 
                $flag = 1;
                break; 
            }
    }

if($flag == 0)
{
    echo "try again<br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is wrong.

First you need to check this way, without any foreach. Just replace your foreach with that:

```
if(array_key_exists($username, $users) && $users[$username] == $password){
   echo "$name  welcome your password is $password";
}
else
  echo "try again<br>"; 
}
```

Secondly it's heavely unsafe to store passwords in plain text! Instead take a look into hashing. Store a hash of the password and compare to that hash:

```
$users = array(
    "Dragos"=>"055A0FCF80E3B5814541A876CB52BB0F3752D51FC52207E1D2BD6778C039A76362C39DA70E84A5C4DFB6DB0CDB5EC81E08C6C2220B2363ED35A40DB5CDB776F5",
    "Cristina"=>"817E2C4A1FE39344168CCCD9D42BA7D79945E16F0116ABF34FBCB12FF815507231042F095F985CC2E3ECAEA10ABDA3EF860B6DB884774E7E5ECB576D16E5852F", 
    "Ionel"=>"937C31238DE673F763590F31E98D133F12F7418E48E0159045CCAD9B9718E00BBE9ED41C83E4469C66F8974E95E3CFD9AA5ACDF274D3C18C742A70CD9F19F62A"
); 
//[...]
if(array_key_exists($username, $users) && $users[$username] == hash("sha512", $password)){
   echo "$name  welcome your password is $password";
}
else
  echo "try again<br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to work with a 'match' flag. Also, since you work with logins, there should only be 1 match and not more than one. This is important if you start using databases.

```
$match = 0;
foreach($users as $name=>$password)  {
        if($name==$username && $password==$pass) { 
             $match++;
        }
}
if {$match == 1) {
        echo 'welcome';
} else {
        echo 'Try again';
}
```